# Override price methods but stop special price appearing?

Tags: price

I need to override the existing price of a product.

I have extend the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price` class and overridden the following methods **getPrice** & **getFinalPrice**.

This does have the desired result, but it is also diplaying the special price. How do I disable this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Special price is shown when `getFinalPrice` and `getPrice` do not return the same value.

You can have a look in the massive file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml` this is where the "magic" happens

Comment: The getFinalPrice and getPrice are returning the same value. The special price is only been displayed on the category page. If I click through to the product itself I don't get the special price.

Comment: do you have a special template for the category page?

Comment: I am using a 3rd party theme. I have not done any changes to the page.